# Upload file in Bottle as is and use it afterwards

Tags: python, file-upload, bottle

I have a problem accessing .csv file, after I upload it.

HTML:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="data" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I only know how to access file, that is located in the folder, is there a way to pass uploaded file as a parameter?

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('4cls.csv'.decode('utf-8')), delimiter=';')
```

Thatnks a lot guys!

Comment: What does your bottle code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out!

HTML:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Python:

```
upload = bottle.request.files.get('upload')
reader = csv.DictReader(upload.file, delimiter=';')
```

and proceed it like an ordinary dictionary.